# Listening to system mouse clicks from Java

Tags: java, swing, java-native-interface, mouseevent, jna

My main aim is to count the number of mouse clicks on a particular application.

Imagine I have opened Microsoft Word and a web browser on my PC. My Java code should tell me how many times I clicked on Word and on the web browser. I need the application name and the number of clicks.

How can I do this? Any solution must work for MAC, Linux and Windows.

Comment: This topic might give you the (unfortunate) explanation u need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869294/detecting-a-mouse-click-anywhere-on-screen-with-java

Comment: I made something like you want in C#, you can use [mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) to run it over the platforms other than windows. I'm at work now so I can't access my sources but if you are interested I can search for it after.

Comment: Thanks friend. i want only java.i dnt know we can do in java or not?.You will found send me yar..

Comment: @HericDenis : Friend can you please send example in c#..

Comment: Sure I do @Manoj, actualy I think my software made something like send clicks to programs but I think it won't be hard to do the other way. Unfortunally I can't do it now since I'm at work, so ASAP I'll try out an example for you.

Comment: @HericDenis: Thanks ya lot.. if its not possible here, you can post me to my mail mahesh.sivasamy@gmail.com

Comment: Okay @Manoj (: I hope this kind of stuff was implemented in mono for MAC and Linux as it works for standard .NET

Comment: @HericDenis: Thanks friend. I'm waiting for you code... it’s possible in java any idea?

Comment: @HericDenis: R u there?.. i'm waiting for your code..

Comment: Oh @Manoj I'm sorry! I really forgot that ;D I'm at work now (just started) it's 7:40 AM here, I'll leave 4:30 PM and then I can look for your code (:

Comment: Yeah @Manoj I forgot that again, I'm on a rush here :/

Comment: @HericDenis:kindly send where ever your free.. but iits urgent.

Comment: Sorry @Manoj but I've got an internship report to finish until friday so I'm a bit busy now; I know that's a long time since I said but I really hadn't time for that. You're still trying another solution, right?

Comment: @HericDenis: Thanks ya ...  now i leaved thats task.. if u done once send me... give me your personal gmail id for we will chat in there...

Answer (score 6):

You could try a library such as jnativehook: http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/. Check out their examples [on this page](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/wiki/examples).

This library uses native functionality to provide access to mouse events that would otherwise be impossible to achieve in pure Java. It appears to support Mac, Linux and Windows.

Comment: Thanks, Dunkan. This library is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know jnativehook jar is to get all mouse event information. But i dint found any source to get the application name where the mouse is clicked currently by the user.

Comment: her i was tired  following infomration got when i click on my mouse                                                                   java.awt.Point[x=543,y=730] | java.awt.FocusEvent[FOCUS_GAINED,permanent,opposite=null,cause=ACTIVATION] on javax.swing.JFrame[frame0,0,0,158x45,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=EXIT_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,9,36,140x0,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]