# How can I get mouse location out of my java application?

Tags: java, swing

I've used class MouseInfor,but it can only help get location on the interface of my app.

How can I get mouse location out of the app? And I read similar questions on this site.

Somebody said I could use JNI or  some API to interact with O.S. So,is there some API

available  or how to use JNI?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer you are looking for is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419555/how-to-obtain-mouse-click-coordinates-outside-my-window-in-java).

Hope this is correct, I apologise if it is not.

Comment: Hi Digger! When you find a duplicate, you should post it as a comment, not as an answer :)

Comment: Looks to me that this other question has a good answer for this problem.

Comment: @glowcoder - apologies, just started using this site again and was not aware that was the case. I shall do that in future.