# how to get x, y position on click of mouse out of frame?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, awt, toolkit

Is there any way to get mouse coordinates on a click of desktop screen, i dont want to click inside the java frame, want to click the mouse pointer straight away on desktop and  have to know the x,y coordinates  ? please help me out? (windows)

`Rectangle rectScreenSize = new Rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2);

BufferedImage biScreen = robot.createScreenCapture (rectScreenSize);`

finally want to pass the coordinates for rectangle, to determine the screen size for robot class?

Comment: *Can you know where I'm clicking on my monitor/Desktop?* The answer is same for your this question.

Comment: @HarryJoy  Do you have a link for that thread?

Comment: I doubt that it's possible since I would think the OS would use a click outside the Java frame to give control to whatever else you click.  I don't know for sure and I'll wait to see what others might say.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a transparent, undecorated JFrame on top of everything, and pass the click on with the **Robot** class.

By the way, the following does not work outside your own window (I had hoped so):

```
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            System.out.println("event: " + event);
            if (event.toString().contains("MOUSE_EXITED")) {
                System.out.println("mouse_exited");
            }
        }
    }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```

Comment: thanks Eggen... but still here,i hope need to click on frame, to get the coordinates.

Comment: @jcrshankar um... can you repost that comment with proper English, please?

Comment: when i have clicked the mouse inside the frame am getting the x,y value,but when i clicked mouse on the window(out of frame) i cant able get it values..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419555/how-to-obtain-mouse-click-coordinates-outside-my-window-in-java

Comment: the above link meets my need partially but still am looking for best solution.,this is similar to Eggens response.