# Find position of mouse outside of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, awt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to obtain mouse click coordinates outside my window in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419555/how-to-obtain-mouse-click-coordinates-outside-my-window-in-java)

I basically need to find out the location of the mouse pointer. i've tried this:

```
package main;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class MouseListen implements MouseMotionListener{

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {     
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        mouseX = arg0.getX();
        mouseY = arg0.getY();
    }

   public int mouseX, mouseY;

}
```

Now that only works when inside the `JFrame` window. How could I possible find the x and y position of the mouse outiside the `JFrame`?

Comment: If you knew how to do that in C, C++ or Assembly, might be [JNI - Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) can help you in this :-)

Comment: This is easy to do with the help of the end user. Just get them to click on a point in a screen shot.  As shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6092439/418556).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the X and Y coordinates of mouse pointer on screen? Try using `MouseEvent.getXOnScreen()` and `MouseEvent.getYOnScreen()` (Since Java 1.6)