# Java-how to tell if cursor has entered a folder or file component on the desktop page

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouseenter

I trying to find a method in java which could tell me when the mouse cursor has entered the borders of a folder or file component. Can anybody refer me to a good document or help me on this?

Comment: Mouse events happen within the context of the Java application (not your desktop).  I don't think this is possible.  The best you can do is check if the cursor has left your Java application.

Comment: Thank you Mohammad. So instead of detecting whether cursor has entered a component or not, I have to simply enable the user to click whenever he decides.a bit messy but it seems thats the way to go.

Comment: @pok You can use [PointerInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html) to get the pointer coordinates, but you cannot know if it has entered something that isn't part of your java UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouse events happen within the `context` of the `Java application` (not your desktop). I don't think this is possible.

The best you can do is check if the cursor has left your Java application.  As user BackSlash mentioned,

> you can use PointerInfo to get the pointer coordinates, but you cannot
>   know if it has entered something that isn't part of your java
>   application.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html

An alternative option is:

> Add an AWTEventListener for focus events. As long as your app has
>   focus before the button is clicked you'll receive a focus lost event.
>   Then query for the pointer position.
>
> The limitation is that, of course, your app loses focus. So depending
>   on what you are ultimately trying to achieve this might not be useful.

Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2420208/2498729