# Java background process to count mouse clicks?

Tags: java, background-process

I have a simple program that takes a mouse click `ActionEvent` and for each occurence, adds one to an integer which is displayed in the console. Currently, the window must be in focus and you have to click on it for it to do anything. How can I remove the need for the frame and the console output and have it run as a background process, as so you would not require focus?

Comment: What would you click on then?

Comment: If you need to do something native to the system maybe another tool/language could be easier. I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, the console will not trigger if you don't launch it, maybe Robot class help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+detect+mouse+click+anywhere

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419555/how-to-obtain-mouse-click-coordinates-outside-my-window-in-java

Comment: And http://kra.lc/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/