# Java getting mouse location

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent, mouse, thread-sleep

This is what i got so far, but this is printing the mouse position every 1000ms, how can I code it such that only when i click on a position it print out the location

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        while (true) {

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("(" + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + ", " + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y + ")");
        }



    }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419555/how-to-obtain-mouse-click-coordinates-outside-my-window-in-java

Comment: *"how can I code it such that only when i click on a position"*  What feature does this bring to the user?  Is it spyware?

Answer (score 0):

Use mouselistener's java swing. you will get the mouse position.

http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/MouseClickExample.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html

Comment: I think OP wants the mouse position not only when clicking inside a GUI window but anywhere on the desktop. Like having his program own window displayed at the top right of his screen and everytime he clicks on a link on the desktop the mouseposition where he globally clicked is shown in the programs own window.

Comment: wad about having to click anywhere on the desktop is it different from the frame ?