# Swing: Catch MouseEvent on Window blocked by modal Dialog?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a JFrame, which opens a modal JDialog.
The JFrame has quiet a few buttons, wich are NOT supposed to be usable, when the JDialog is open -> therefore, modal JDialog.
But when the area outside the JDialog is clicked, the JDialog is supposed to close. The solution I outline below doesn't catch any MouseEvents on the JFrame, though.

I now need to figure out if a user clicked on the Window but outside the JDialog.
Reason to do this as per comment: The JDialog is supposed to close once the user clicks outside it!
My best guess currently is to create an AWTEventListener (As in [how to obtain mouse click coordinates outside my window in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419555/how-to-obtain-mouse-click-coordinates-outside-my-window-in-java)):

```
        listener = new AWTEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            if (!event.getSource().getClass().equals(ButtonDialog.class)
                    && event.getID() == 502) {
                ButtonDialog.this.dispose();
            }
        }
    };
```

and then add it when the JDialog opened:

```
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(
                    listener, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
```

Unfortunately, when the Dialog is modal, no AWT-events seem to be happening outside that Dialog.
I have considered using the GlassPane of the JFrame instead, but that really seems impractical.
Can I catch events on a "modally-blocked" Windows like this at all? Or am I on the totally wrong track?

Comment: *"I now need to figure out if a user clicked on the Window but outside the JDialog."*  ..why?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Thanks! Yep, I actually totally forgot why I even need to catch that click ^^

Comment: Voting to close as a problem that can no longer be reproduced; if not, please update the question.

Comment: Please explain the close request? I still have the problem... or is this a request for more example code?

Comment: I interpreted your comment to mean that you no longer "need to catch that click." If you _do_ need to respond to a click, why not use a modeless dialog?

Comment: The widow that opened the JDialog is supposed to be blocked -> modal does that just fine. But IF someone clicks outside the Modal Dialog, it is supposed to close.

Comment: I don't this your users understand the concept of a blocking dialog. Why make it blocking if you can just click on the window to close the dialog? You are not describing your problem effectively. I also agree this is an XY problem.